# Prevent buffering of HTTP streams on iOS

Tags: ios, http, http-headers, comet, umts

I'm in the process of implementing a HTTP server using long lived HTTP requests 
to stream real-time information to the browser.
Im most situations it is working fine. But I still see a problem when trying to access the page from a iPad connected over UMTS.

It seems like there is some buffering going on. I can only see updates after more than 2 KB were sent. The next updates take another 2 KB to be displayed. And so forth. Please note that this doesn't happen when the iPad is connected over WiFi.

I can imagine that some HTTP header value has to be set to prevent the buffering. I already tried the following headers without any effect.

```
X-NoBuffering: 1
X-NoCompression: 1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Cache-Control: private
```

The alternative to stretch each update to at least 2 KB is of course possible. But it doesn't seem neccessary in every other situation.

Comment: HTTP headers don't have anything to do with network buffering. Can you set the TCP Push flag and/or disable Nagle ("no delay")? What language are you implementing the server in?

Comment: post your request/update code.

Comment: the "server" your implementing is not residing on an iOS device i hope?  The iOS device is the client right?

Comment: The server is implemented in C++. iOS is the client. My testcase sends 82 bytes every second. I see only updates after every 27 seconds. I dont think that nagle waits 27 seconds. But I will try.

Comment: @CodeCaster Just tried to enable TCP_NODELAY. It has no effect. What do you meen with TCP Push flag?

Comment: Nevermind, I just [read](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/408135) most sockets API's don't expose the PSH flag. It must be something network-related, perhaps even the UMTS provider buffers data until enough for a full packet is ready.

Comment: You send your test case sends 82 bytes a second...why"  Is this from the server to the client? the 82 bytes per second?

Comment: please paste your HTTP request code.

Comment: you cant send 82 bytes a second from server to client and expect a response in the client.

Comment: @stackmonster My HTTP request is made from an iframe. I just set the iframe.src property an be done. Nothing special. Why can't I expect to receive 82 bytes in time? I see no upper bound on the timeout. This is an endless HTTP response.

Comment: because the buffers are not full - when the client buffer is full you will be able to do something, thats the way it works.  I guess I dont understand what your trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @stackmonster Thats of course not the way TCP works. TCP delays the sending of small packets (see nagle algorithm/TCP_NODELAY). But doesn't hold the data indefinitly back.

Comment: HTTP buffering certainly does

Comment: Okay, now we are back to my original question. What HTTP header field influences this buffering, if any?